# How do I split a string, breaking at a word before a character?

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following string

```
'Material: Metall & PVC Size: Ø 32 mm Weight: 8 gram'
```

Using JavaScript, what is the fastest way to parse this into:

```
var title = ["Material:", "Size:", "Weight:"];
var property = ["Metall & PVC", "Ø 32 mm", "8 gram"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var regex = new RegExp(title.join("|"));
var input = 'Material: Metall & PVC Size: Ø 32 mm Weight: 8 gram';
var property = input.split( regex ).slice(-(title.length));
```

**DEMO**

```js
var title = ["Material:", "Size:", "Weight:"];
var input = 'Material: Metall & PVC Size: Ø 32 mm Weight: 8 gram';

var regex = new RegExp(title.join("|"));
var property = input.split(regex).slice(-(title.length)).map( function(item){ return item.trim(); });

console.log(property);
```

Comment: Great solution! How would I get the title as well?

Comment: @WalentinWidgren but you already have the title with you, right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But I need to get the title parsed as well.

Comment: For that you need to keep a delimiter between first value and second title as well.

Answer (score 1):

To get the titles.

```js
var string, titles;
string = 'Material: Metall & PVC Size: Ø 32 mm Weight: 8 gram';
titles = string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+:/g);
console.log(titles);
```

Use regular expression `/[a-zA-Z]+:/g`

To remove `:` from titles

```js
var string, titles;
string = 'Material: Metall & PVC Size: Ø 32 mm Weight: 8 gram';
titles = string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+:/g);
for (var i = 0, len = titles.length; i < len; i++) {
  titles[i] = titles[i].slice(0, -1);
}
console.log(titles);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that regex is not cheap, and this will not work if you have spaces in your titles, but I think this can be a good starting point for you.

```
var string='Material: Metall & PVC Size: Ø 32 mm Weight: 8 gram';
var title=[], properties=[];
string.split(/(\w+:) /).forEach(function(element,index){
  if(index>0){// ignore first empty element
    if(index%2==1){
      title.push(element); // collect titles
    }else{
      properties.push(element); // collect properties
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Would like to up vote this but unfortunately my reputation is to low.  I have heard that regex can cause some performance issues. But are there any alternatives?

Comment: Yes, you can develop a parser (lexer) for your line format and collect your titles and properties with it. But in your case, that will be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = 'Material: Metall & PVC Size: Ø 32 mm Weight: 8 gram';
var title = string.match(/[^ ]+:/g);
var property = string.split(/ ?[^ ]+: ?/g).splice(1);
console.log(title, property);
```